# Octave/MATLAB vs. Python On An Embedded Computer

Tags: python, image-processing, embedded, octave

I want to perform image processing on a low-end (Atom processor) embedded computer or microcontroller that is running Linux.

I'm trying to decide whether I should write my image processing code in Octave or Python. I feel comfortable in both languages, but is there any reason why I should use one over the other? Are there huge performance differences? I feel as though Octave may more closely resemble, syntax-wise, the domain of image processing than Python.

Thanks for your input.

Edit: The motivation for this question comes from the fact that I design in Octave and get a working algorithm and then port the algorithm to C++. I am trying to avoid this double work and go from design to deployment easily.

Comment: What kind of processing do you intend to implement (simple thresholding or complicated detection algorithms)?  Do you have any performance requirements? (one time run on an image vs real-time video?) Picking the right tool is very much dependent on what you want to get done.

Comment: We intend to do rather complicated computer vision algorithms, including detection within an image. Our system is not time-critical and has a "loop" rate of roughly 0.2Hz, or not very fast.

Answer (score 2):

I am bit surprised that you don't stick to C/C++ - many convenient image processing libraries exists. Even though, I have like 20 years of experience with C, 8 years of experience with Matlab and only 1 years of experience with Python, I would choose Python together with OpenCV, which is an extremely optimized library for computer vision supporting Intel Performance Primitives. Once you have a working Python solution, it is easy to translate this to C or C++ to get the additional performance or reduce the power consumption. I would start with Python and Numpy using matplotlib for displaying / prototyping, optimize using OpenCV from within Python and finally use C++ and test it against the Python reference implementation.

Comment: While there are certainly many convenient and optimized libraries out there, I'm trying to avoid the double-work of designing in a high-level environment such as Octave/MATLAB and then porting the code to a more strict language like C++. We are currently leaning towards Python but I wanted to also see if there are arguments for sticking with Octave.

Comment: Okay, if running your image processing from within Octave or Python is fast enough you could stick to working with an interpreted language. Speed-wise Python is way superior to Octave - even if you stick to Numpy.

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB has a code generation feature which could potentially help with your workflow. Have a look at [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/code-generation-for-feature-matching-and-registration.html). My understanding is that the Atom is x86 architecture, so the generated code [ought](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102370) to work on it too. You could consider getting a [Trial](https://www.mathworks.com/programs/trials/trial_request.html?prodcode=VP) version and giving the above example a spin on your specific target to evaluate performance and inspect the generated C code.